# Main method waits mid-execution for threads to complete. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I am writing an elevator simulator that runs each elevator in a separate thread. Each elevator owns it's own ArrayList of destinations. In my main method I am calling on elevator 2 to move to floor 14. While it is traveling to 14 I tell it stop at 13 (which it does before 14). While it is traveling to 13 and 14 I also tell it to travel to 15. However, I've discovered my main method stops after the request for floor 14, waits for the elevator to reach 14, and then finally executes the request for floor 15.

Why is it doing this? I can't figure it out.

Here is my output:

```
00:00:00:000  Creating building...
00:00:00:012  Building created - 16 floors, 4 elevators
00:00:00:014  Elevator 1 going to Floor 11 for UP request [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:00:015  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 1 to Floor 2 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:00:520  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 2 to Floor 3 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:018  Elevator 2 going to Floor 14 for UP request [Floor Requests: 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:020  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 1 to Floor 2 [Floor Requests: 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:021  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 3 to Floor 4 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:521  Elevator 2 going to Floor 13 for UP request [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:523  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 4 to Floor 5 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:01:523  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 2 to Floor 3 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:02:025  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 5 to Floor 6 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:02:026  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 3 to Floor 4 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:02:529  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 6 to Floor 7 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:02:530  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 4 to Floor 5 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:03:032  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 7 to Floor 8 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:03:032  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 5 to Floor 6 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:03:537  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 8 to Floor 9 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:03:539  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 6 to Floor 7 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:04:040  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 9 to Floor 10 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:04:042  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 7 to Floor 8 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:04:542  Elevator 1 moving from Floor 10 to Floor 11 [Floor Requests: 11, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:04:544  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 8 to Floor 9 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:05:047  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 9 to Floor 10 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:05:047  Elevator 1 Doors Open
00:00:05:551  Elevator 1 Doors Close
00:00:05:550  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 10 to Floor 11 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:06:054  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 11 to Floor 12 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:06:556  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 12 to Floor 13 [Floor Requests: 13, 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:07:062  Elevator 2 Doors Open
00:00:07:566  Elevator 2 Doors Close
00:00:07:567  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 13 to Floor 14 [Floor Requests: 14, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:08:069  Elevator 2 Doors Open
00:00:08:570  Elevator 2 Doors Close
00:00:08:571  Let's see when this is being called00:00:08:572  Elevator 2 going to Floor 15 for UP request [Floor Requests: 15, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:08:572  Elevator 2 moving from Floor 14 to Floor 15 [Floor Requests: 15, ][Rider Requests:]
00:00:09:076  Elevator 2 Doors Open
00:00:09:582  Elevator 2 Doors Close
```

Main method:

public class ElevatorSimulatorMain {

```
private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // make a building with elevators
    System.out.println(getTimeStamp() + "Creating building...");
    Building testBuilding = new Building(16, 4); //16 floors and 4 elevators
    System.out.printf(getTimeStamp()
            + "Building created - %d floors, %d elevators\n", 
            testBuilding.getNumFloors(), testBuilding.getNumElevators());

    // create a thread for each elevator
    for (int i = 1; i <= testBuilding.getNumElevators(); i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(testBuilding.getPassengerElevatorbyID(i));
        t.start();
    }

    // Elevator 1 to floor 11
    try {
        testBuilding.getController().sendElevator(11, 1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ElevatorSimulatorMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // Elevator 2 to floor 14
    try {
        testBuilding.getController().sendElevator(14, 2);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ElevatorSimulatorMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // Elevator 2 to floor 13 while still in transit to floor 14
    try {
        testBuilding.getController().sendElevator(13, 2);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ElevatorSimulatorMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() + "Let's see when this is being called");
    // Elevator 2 to floor 15 while still in transit to floor 13
    try {
        testBuilding.getController().sendElevator(15, 2);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ElevatorSimulatorMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

PassengerElevator Thread

public PassengerElevator(int elevID) {

```
    this.elevID = elevID;
    travelSpeed = 500;  // in milliseconds
    doorSpeed = 500;    // in milliseconds
    currentFloor = 1;
    defaultFloor = 1;
    currentState = Direction.IDLE;
    tempDestinations = new ArrayList<>();
    upDestinations = new ArrayList<>();
    downDestinations = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    boolean running = true; // flag for keeping the thread running

    while (running) {
        try {
            synchronized (tempDestinations) {
                if (upDestinations.isEmpty() && downDestinations.isEmpty()){
                    tempDestinations.wait();
                    if (!downDestinations.isEmpty()) {
                        processDownRequest();
                    }
                    else if (!upDestinations.isEmpty()) {
                        processUpRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted! Going back to check for " +
                    "requests/wait");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Make elevator go up one floor. Takes travelSpeed time
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void moveUp() throws InterruptedException {
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor++);
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
}

/**
 * Make elevator go down one floor. Takes travelSpeed time
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void moveDown() throws InterruptedException{
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor--);
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
}

/**
 * Make elevator door open for doorSpeed time. When door is open people
 * move into elevator
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void openDoors() throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() + "Elevator %d "
            + "Doors Open\n", elevID);
    Thread.sleep(doorSpeed);
    System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() + "Elevator %d "
            + "Doors Close\n", elevID);
}

/**
 * Moves the elevator up to the first destination in upDestinations.
 * When it gets there, it removes the destination from upDestinations.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
private void processUpRequest() throws InterruptedException {

    while (!upDestinations.isEmpty()) {
        if (currentFloor != upDestinations.get(0)) {
            currentState = Direction.UP;
            System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() 
                    + "Elevator %d moving from Floor %d to Floor %d "
                    + "[Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n", elevID,
                    currentFloor, ++currentFloor, 
                    printRequests(upDestinations));
            moveUp();
        }
        else {
            upDestinations.remove(0);
            openDoors();
        }
    }
    currentState = Direction.IDLE;
}

/**
 * Moves the elevator down to the first destination in downDestinations.
 * When it gets there, it removes the destination from downDestinations.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
private void processDownRequest() throws InterruptedException {

    while (!downDestinations.isEmpty()) {
        if (currentFloor != downDestinations.get(0)) {
            currentState = Direction.DOWN;
            System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() 
                    + "Elevator %d moving from Floor %d to Floor %d "
                    + "[Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n", elevID,
                    currentFloor, --currentFloor, 
                    printRequests(downDestinations));
            moveDown();
        }
        else {
            downDestinations.remove(0);
            openDoors();
        }
    }
    currentState = Direction.IDLE;
}

/**
 * add a destination for the elevator to stop at
 * @param floor for the elevator to travel to
 */
public void addDestination(int floor) {

    // if elevator is moving down
    if (!downDestinations.isEmpty() && currentState == Direction.DOWN) {
        addDestinationWhenMovingDown(floor);
    }

    // if elevator is moving UP  
    else if (!upDestinations.isEmpty() && currentState == Direction.UP) {
        addDestinationWhenMovingUp(floor);
    }

    // if elevator is IDLE
    else {
        addDestinationWhenIdle(floor);
    }

    /* 
    this is just an object to conveniently call on to indicate there must
    have been a destination added since you cannot call wait on 
    upDestinations and downDestinations at the same time.
    */
    synchronized (tempDestinations) {
        tempDestinations.notifyAll();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle adding a destination when the elevator state is idle.
 * @param floor - the floor the request was made on
 */
private void addDestinationWhenIdle(int floor) {

    // request to go UP
    if (floor > currentFloor) {
        upDestinations.add(floor);
        System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() 
                + "Elevator %d going to Floor %d for UP request"
                + " [Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n",elevID, 
                upDestinations.get(0), 
                printRequests(upDestinations));
    }

    // request to go DOWN
    else if (floor < currentFloor) {
            downDestinations.add(floor);
            System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp()
                    + "Elevator %d going to Floor %d for DOWN request"
                    + " [Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n",elevID, 
                    downDestinations.get(0), 
                    printRequests(downDestinations));
    }

    // already on that floor, do nothing
    else {}
}

/**
 * Handle adding a destination when the elevator is moving up. Checks to see
 * if request is in the destination list already. If it isn't, it adds it to
 * the list and sorts the list in order of when the elevator should go first
 * @param floor - the floor the request was made on
 */
private void addDestinationWhenMovingUp(int floor) {
    // if it isn't already in the list, add it and sort it.
    // do nothing if it is already in the list
    if (!upDestinations.contains(floor)) {
        upDestinations.add(floor);
        Collections.sort(upDestinations);
        System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp() 
                + "Elevator %d going to Floor %d for UP request"
                + " [Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n",elevID, 
                upDestinations.get(0), 
                printRequests(upDestinations));
    }
}

/**
 * Handle adding a destination when the elevator is moving down. Checks to 
 * see if request is in the destination list already. If it isn't, it adds 
 * it to the list and sorts the list in order of when the elevator should go
 * first.
 * @param floor - the floor the request was made on
 */
private void addDestinationWhenMovingDown(int floor) {
    // if it isn't already in the list, add it and sort it.
    // do nothing if it is already in the list
    if (!downDestinations.contains(floor)) {
        downDestinations.add(floor);
        Collections.sort(upDestinations);
        Collections.reverse(upDestinations);
        System.out.printf(ElevatorSimulatorMain.getTimeStamp()
                + "Elevator %d going to Floor %d for DOWN request"
                + " [Floor Requests: %s][Rider Requests:]\n",elevID, 
                downDestinations.get(0), 
                printRequests(downDestinations));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer, not as an update to your question. Otherwise, people will think that this question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The locked tempDestinationsList was holding the lock while the elevator movement methods were trying to execute. I changed the lock to release and then the methods for processes request were called.

Here is the fixed snippet of code: @Override public void run() {

```
boolean running = true; // flag for keeping the thread running

while (running) {
    try {
        synchronized (tempDestinations) {
            if (upDestinations.isEmpty() && downDestinations.isEmpty()){
                tempDestinations.wait();
            }
        }
        if (!downDestinations.isEmpty()) {
            processDownRequest();
        }
        else if (!upDestinations.isEmpty()) {
            processUpRequest();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted! Going back to check for " +
                "requests/wait");
    }
}
```